# Inner join in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to do inner join on username where table1 has data like:

```
username    pass
apple       11
orange      22
banana      33
```

With table2 has data like

```
username    email 
tw-apple    apple@gmail.com
fb-orange   orange@gmail.com
reg-banana  banana@gmail.com
```

To get pass and email.

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
        ON table2.(SUBSTRING(`username`,(LOCATE('-',`username`)+1)))=table1.username
```

and also with

```
table2.(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`username`, '-', -1))
```

Need help..

Comment: Try moving the table2 alias to its column references: `ON (SUBSTRING(table2.username,(LOCATE('', table2.username)+1)))=table1.username`

Comment: first of all what you want, if understand correctly you wants to display the username in both table...

Comment: I want to do inner join on both the tables on username omitting the values before '-' on username of table 2

Comment: Thanks @AgRizzo i got the idea

Comment: `table2.username` should really be split into two separate columns in order to preserve referential integrity (which would make this problem go away).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, you can just use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), instead of it clumsy emulation:

```
  SELECT *,table2.username as uname
    FROM table1 
         INNER JOIN table2 
             ON table1.username = SUBSTRING_INDEX(table2.username,'-', -1);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae27b/1) (stole sqlfiddle template from @RagingBull)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  SELECT *,table2.username as uname
  FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
  table2 ON table1.username=(SUBSTRING(table2.username,(LOCATE('-', table2.username))+1))
```

Result:

```
USERNAME    PASS    EMAIL               UNAME
apple       11      apple@gmail.com     tw-apple
orange      22      orange@gmail.com    fb-orange
banana      33      banana@gmail.com    reg-banana
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1b5a/18).

Read more about [`Locate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and [`Substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring).